# identifying sub-arrays in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two two dimensional arrays `a` and `b`  (#columns of a <= #columns in b).  I would like to find an efficient way of matching a row in array `a` to a contiguous part of a row in array `b`.

```
a = np.array([[ 25,  28],
              [ 84,  97],
              [105,  24],
              [ 28, 900]])

b = np.array([[ 25,  28,  84,  97],
              [ 22,  25,  28, 900],
              [ 11,  12, 105,  24]])
```

The output should be `np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [2,2], [3,1]])`.  Row 0 in array `a` matches Row 0 in array `b` (first two positions).  Row 1 in array `a` matches row 0 in array `b` (third and fourth positions).

Comment: What about `[0, 1]` (middle two numbers in `b` match row 0 in `a`)?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to give a simple built-in solution. The condition is too unusual, you need to write your own.

Comment: Building on Paul's comment, how do you handle the case of multiple matches?  We see that `[25, 28]` is found in both rows 0 and 1.

Comment: @rayryeng.  my bad.  I just edited the output.  All matches should be reported.  Exception is when there are multiple matches with the same row.

Comment: @PaulPanzer, yes that was an error and has now been fixed.  Thx.

Comment: As a related sub-question, is there an efficient numpy way to check if there is "match" between two 1D arrays when one is wholly contained in the other?  `np.array([25,28])` is contained in `np.array([34,12,25,28])` but not in `np.array([25,34,28,34])`.  Thx.

Comment: Shouldn't it be : `[[0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]]` considering the multiple matches?

Comment: @Divakar, I have updated the desired output.  I get exactly this with the `transpose()`.  First index is a row from matrix a and second one is a row from matrix b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can leverage [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) based [`scikit-image's view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) for efficient patch extraction, and then compare those patches against each row off `a`, all of it in a vectorized manner. Then, get the matching indices with `np.argwhere` -

```
# a and b from posted question
In [325]: from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

In [428]: w = view_as_windows(b,(1,a.shape[1]))

In [429]: np.argwhere((w == a).all(-1).any(-2))[:,::-1]
Out[429]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [3, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

Alternatively, we could get the indices by the order of rows in `a` by *pushing forward* the first axis of `a` while performing broadcasted comparisons -

```
In [444]: np.argwhere((w[:,:,0] == a[:,None,None,:]).all(-1).any(-1))
Out[444]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 1]])
```

Comment: Awesome answer, @Divakar.  Q: shouldn't that be `np.argwhere((w==a).all(-1).any(-2).transpose())`?  I added a row to `a` and saw things were slightly off.

Comment: what is the advantage of the second (broadcasted comparisons) approach?  It seems to be 3x slower.  Could that be expected to use lesser memory?

Comment: @ironv That was meant more to get the order right, not so much on perfomance. Memory-wise should be the same, but I guess the way it's extended isn't optimal on performance.

Answer (score 1):

Another way I can think of is to loop over each row in `a` and perform a 2D correlation between the `b` which you can consider as a 2D signal a row in `a`. 
 We would find the results which are equal to the sum of squares of all values in `a`.  If we subtract our correlation result with this sum of squares, we would find matches with a zero result.  Any rows that give you a 0 result would mean that the subarray was found in that row.  If you are using floating-point numbers for example, you may want to compare with some small threshold that is just above 0.

If you can use SciPy, the [`scipy.signal.correlate2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html) method is what I had in mind.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import correlate2d

a = np.array([[ 25,  28],
              [ 84,  97],
              [105,  24]])

b = np.array([[ 25,  28,  84,  97],
              [ 22,  25,  28, 900],
              [ 11,  12, 105,  24]])

EPS = 1e-8
result = []
for (i, row) in enumerate(a):
    out = correlate2d(b, row[None,:], mode='valid') - np.square(row).sum()
    locs = np.where(np.abs(out) <= EPS)[0]

    unique_rows = np.unique(locs)
    for res in unique_rows:
        result.append((i, res))
```

We get:

```
In [32]: result
Out[32]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (2, 2)]
```

The time complexity of this could be better, especially since we're looping over each row of `a` to find any subarrays in `b`.